# ORDER BY in SQL where column is synthetic string with embedded integer

Tags: sql, sql-server, h2

I have the following table :

```
CREATE TABLE TEST 
(
     name VARCHAR(10), 
     date_of_entry DATE, 
     flag1 INT, 
     flag2 INT,
     salary FLOAT, 
     flag3 INT,
     id INT
);
```

with the following rows :

```
name    date_of_entry   flag1   flag2   salary      flag3   id
--------------------------------------------------------------
AGMA    2018-11-08      0       1       265466940   1       1
AGMA    2018-11-08      0       1       220737125   1       2
AGMA    2018-11-08      0       1       181270493   0       3
AGMA    2018-11-08      0       1       8584205     0       4
```

I would like to execute the following SQL to order the rows in a specific manner :

```
SELECT 
    name
    + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(8), date_of_entry, 112) 
    + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(1), flag1)
    + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(1), flag2)
    + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(2555), salary)
    + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(1), flag3)
    + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(1), id) AS SYNTHETIC_ORDER
FROM 
    TEST
ORDER BY 
    SYNTHETIC_ORDER DESC
```

However, the salary column gets sorted incorrectly within the string. So my end result is (when executed within Microsoft SQL Server) :

```
SYNTHETIC_ORDER
-----------------------------------
AGMA.20181108.0.1.8.58421e+006.0.4
AGMA.20181108.0.1.2.65467e+008.1.1
AGMA.20181108.0.1.2.20737e+008.1.2
AGMA.20181108.0.1.1.8127e+008.0.3
```

As can be noted, the result is that id 4 comes first, when I want id 1 to come first.

Expected result :

```
SYNTHETIC_ORDER
-----------------------------------
AGMA.20181108.0.1.2.65467e+008.1.1
AGMA.20181108.0.1.2.20737e+008.1.2
AGMA.20181108.0.1.1.8127e+008.0.3
AGMA.20181108.0.1.8.58421e+006.0.4
```

Is there a way to ensure that the salary is correctly ordered in this SQL?

Comment: just change the `ORDER BY` to `ORDER BY id`?, or `ORDER BY salary DESC`, I don't know which one you want

Comment: added tag for db server

Comment: @Lamak - to me the question is clear. But let me clarify, when salary is converted to a string, the database server orders salary within the overall string as a string, one digit at a time. Thus making 8584205 > 265466940. Thus your comment would not help.

Comment: **Side note:** If you're dealing with precise numbers, such as anything to do with **money**, I would recommend to **NOT** use `FLOAT` (or `REAL` or `DOUBLE`), but use `DECIMAL(p,s)` instead

Comment: @Lamak - no it will not address my question. I need the ordering to be date_of_entry, flag1, flag2, salary, flag3, in that order. Adding an order by after the fact will not fix that in the general case.

Comment: Please add the expected results in the question

Comment: Does the textual value of Salary have to be human-readable, or is it sufficient that it sort correctly?

Comment: Can't you simply `ORDER BY name, date_of_entry, flag1, flag2, salary, flag3, id`? What do you need the SYNTHETIC_ORDER for anyway?

Comment: @DavidDubois - it just has to sort correctly.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - unfortunately SYNTHETIC_ORDER comes due to a different requirement. Ultimately I need to get the max(synthetic_order). So, no, I can't simply order by name, date_of_entry, flag1, flag2, salary, flag3, id

Comment: @algorithmic - This sounds strange to me.  Are you maybe looking for something like [tag:greatest-n-per-group]?  (Where the 'greatest' is the maximum salary)

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse, in fact it is 'greatest-n-per-group', but due to the fact that an order by is not allowed in a derived table, I am unable to use that idea.

Comment: Uh, yeah?  But you haven't shown that you need a derived table, so I'm a little confused as to why that's a problem?  Normally you use other constructs to get the maximum, not an `ORDER BY` directly.  Note that your current query will ignore the use of indices, among other things.

Comment: I simplified the problem to what I wanted (the actual query is much more complex) - essentially how do I order an integer correctly when it is embedded within a string composed of multiple columns. I think Caius Jard's answer is closest and is the least likely to have unintended results. The other way is to normalize the integer, but the act of normalization by itself is not that straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed width rep and it uses only functions available in both H2 (not tagged) and SQLS (tagged):

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(
      CAST(name as CHAR(10)), --right pad to 10, 

      YEAR(date_of_entry),
      RIGHT(CONCAT('0',MONTH(date_of_entry)),2),
      RIGHT(CONCAT('0',DAY(date_of_entry)),2), --yyyymmdd

      CAST(flag1 as CHAR(1)), --rpad to 1, doesn't need cast if never null/0 length

      CAST(flag2 as CHAR(1)), --maybe doesn't need cast, see above

      RIGHT(CONCAT('0000000000', CAST(salary AS INT)),10), --lpad with 0 to 10 wide

      CAST(flag3 as CHAR(1)), --maybe doesn't need cast, see above

      RIGHT(CONCAT('0000000000', id), 10) --lpad with 0 to 10 wide

    ) AS SYNTHETIC_ORDER
FROM 
    TEST
ORDER BY 
    SYNTHETIC_ORDER DESC
```

Points of note:

- Your CREATE TABLE statement doesn't mention ID, but your query does; included ID
- Your query doesn't mention NAME but your example data output does; included NAME
- You might not need to pad the ID or salary so much
- Come of the casts to chars (e.g. on flag columns) can be dropped (if the flag column is 100% guaranteed to always be 1 char long)
- If salary max value in table is larger than an int can hold, consider a cast to something else
- By padding the salary with leading zeroes, the sort will work out. Normalising it to between 0 and 1 could also work, if all the values were padded out to the same width but you possibly then get the problem that loss of precision (dividing a 10 digit salary down to eg 0.123456) will cause two different salaries to merge because there aren't enough digits to fully represent. With any division-that-quantizes-to-lower precision you then risk the original values sorting wrongly (e.g. If salaries of 1000000000 and 1000000001 with id of 2 and 1 respectively both normalise to 0.123456 they would end up sorted wrongly. To guard against this you probably need as many digits for the division answer as the salary had in the first place, padded to a fixed width, but if you've gone that far you might as well just pad all the salaries out either to the width of the widest or to some width that will contain them all. Here utilising a cast to an int might be handy, if the int will overflow. You can make a decision to pad to one digit wider than an int will hold and then if someone inserts a large value in future and your query starts failing because of overflow it at least won't silently deliver wrong results because the pad is chopping digits off the left hand edge. In addressing the cast to bit you can choose whether to add some logic that pads out to the LENGTH() of the string form of the SELECT MAX salary

CONCAT is nice cos you can pass most types to it without first casting to varchar, and it doesn't null the whole thing if you concat a null on, unlike regular string concat ops with + or ||

Comment: In MS SQL Server - Msg 174, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
The right function requires 2 argument(s).

Comment: Added a missing bracket

Comment: I am going to accept this as the right answer. You may want to add a note that lpadding the salary causes the sort to work correctly. I think thats a better idea than normalization of the number.

Comment: Added some further notes on the padding of salary- perhaps future considerations

Answer (score 3):

Why can't you just order it by the individual columns?

```
SELECT 
    date_of_entry, flag1, flag2, salary, flag3 
    , name
        + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(8), date_of_entry, 112) 
        + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(1), flag1)
        + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(1), flag2)
        + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(2555), salary)
        + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(1), flag3)
        + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(1), id) AS SYNTHETIC_ORDER
FROM  TEST
ORDER BY date_of_entry DESC, flag1 DESC, flag2 DESC, salary DESC, flag3 DESC
```

This will get you the MAX.

```
SELECT SYNTHETIC_ORDER
FROM (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY date_of_entry DESC, flag1 DESC, flag2 DESC, salary DESC, flag3 DESC) AS RowNum
        , name
            + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(8), date_of_entry, 112) 
            + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(1), flag1)
            + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(1), flag2)
            + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(2555), salary)
            + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(1), flag3)
            + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(1), id) AS SYNTHETIC_ORDER
    FROM  TEST
) a
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

Comment: I can't do that because I need to use this query as a subquery and get the max(synthetic_order).

Comment: Then bring the order by in the main query.

Comment: Can't you just wrap it in subquery to get the max?

Comment: You missed id off your rownumber orderby?

Answer (score 2):

This will get you what you want but maybe not in a way you like fun to the sub-query

```
SELECT 
    name
    + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(8), date_of_entry, 112) 
    + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(1), flag1)
    + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(1), flag2)
    + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(2555), salary / (SELECT MIN(salary) AS min_sal FROM TEST))
    + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(1), flag3)
    + '.' + CONVERT(varchar(1), id) AS SYNTHETIC_ORDER
FROM TEST 
ORDER BY SYNTHETIC_ORDER DESC
```

Comment: I like this idea. but what if there is an additional row where salary is 1?

Comment: @algorithmic It doesn't work when I tried that but then I multiplied the result of MIN() by pi (3.14) and it sorted correctly but maybe then it turns more into a hack. Do you really expect such a range?

Comment: I just need a more general solution. I started looking at the idea of normalization of salary so that it fits between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try:

```
SELECT name
+ '.' + CONVERT(varchar(8), date_of_entry, 112) 
+ '.' + CONVERT(varchar(1), flag1)
+ '.' + CONVERT(varchar(1), flag2)
+ '.' + CHAR(DIGITS(salary))
+ '.' + CONVERT(varchar(1), flag3)
+ '.' + CONVERT(varchar(1), id) AS SYNTHETIC_ORDER
FROM TEST
ORDER BY SYNTHETIC_ORDER DESC
```

Comment: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 20
'DIGITS' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your query to

```
SELECT 
name
+ '.' + CONVERT(varchar(8), date_of_entry, 112) 
+ '.' + CONVERT(varchar(1), flag1)
+ '.' + CONVERT(varchar(1), flag2)
+ '.' + CONVERT(varchar(2555), salary)
+ '.' + CONVERT(varchar(1), flag3)
+ '.' + CONVERT(varchar(1), id) AS SYNTHETIC_ORDER
FROM 
    TEST
ORDER BY 
    salary DESC
```

Comment: No, this wont work. I am not trying to order by salary alone. I am trying to order first by date_of_entry, then flag1, flag2, salary and finally flag3. In order to achieve this I could order by each of the fields individually, however the reason for creating the SYNTHETIC_ORDER is for other purposes and cannot be changed.

Comment: SELECT 
name
+ '.' + CONVERT(varchar(8), date_of_entry, 112) 
+ '.' + CONVERT(varchar(1), flag1)
+ '.' + CONVERT(varchar(1), flag2)
+ '.' + CONVERT(varchar(2555), salary)
+ '.' + CONVERT(varchar(1), flag3)
+ '.' + CONVERT(varchar(1), id) AS SYNTHETIC_ORDER

FROM TEST ORDER BY date_of_entry,flag1,flag2,salary,flag3 DESC

Answer (score 1):

If you need the "max" synthetic order, simply do:

```
select top (1) name, date_of_entry, falg1, flag2, salary, flag3, id
from test
order by name desc, date_of_entry desc, flag1 desc, flag2 desc, salary desc, flag3 desc, id desc;
```

I don't see a reason to stuff these values into a string.

If you want a separate row for each `name`, then:

```
select top (1) with ties name, date_of_entry, falg1, flag2, salary, flag3, id
from test
order by row_number() over (partition by name desc order by date_of_entry desc, flag1 desc, flag2 desc, salary desc, flag3 desc, id desc);
```

Comment: In the example I only listed one name. Actually, I could have multiple name values. TOP(1) wont give me the max within a name.

Comment: @algorithmic . . . That really doesn't complicate the issue very much.  A synthetic string is not the right way to go.

Comment: in this case it does. I also have to take into account the limitation that my unit test database used by my team is H2. This means any SQL I implement has to be executable within H2 since we unit test our SQL code.

Comment: @algorithmic - that way lies madness; you're writing your executing code to account for limitations in your testing framework, which is problematic for a number of reasons.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse - indeed, you are correct. We have identified this as a defeciency. But we do have to be practical. We have a database that is ours and there the unit test database is exactly the same as the production one. But where we connect to other databases (sybase and DB2) at this point we dont have the bandwidth to create unit test dbs for each member of our team that is an instance of one of those and there we use H2.

Comment: @algorithmic - use a [dockerized image of the database](https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/db2express-c/), test data pre-loaded, which also solves the problem of resetting the data for each test (since you want the tests to be isolated).

Answer (score 1):

Sir,

As soon as you convert it to a huge string(varchar), it follows alphabetical order instead of order of magnitude like you are expecting.

Can't you just use a row_number as your "Synthetic order". In other words, instead of this:

```
SELECT 
name
+ '.' + CONVERT(varchar(8), date_of_entry, 112) 
+ '.' + CONVERT(varchar(1), flag1)
+ '.' + CONVERT(varchar(1), flag2)
+ '.' + CONVERT(varchar(2555), salary)
+ '.' + CONVERT(varchar(1), flag3)
+ '.' + CONVERT(varchar(1), id) AS SYNTHETIC_ORDER
FROM 
   TEST
ORDER BY 
   SYNTHETIC_ORDER DESC
```

this:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    row_number() over (order by date_of_entry,flag1,flag2,salary,flag3,id) as SYNTHETIC_ORDER
FROM 
   TEST
ORDER BY 
   SYNTHETIC_ORDER DESC
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following routine.

In your code, you write `CONVERT(varchar(2555), salary)`. This doesn't work because when you convert a float to a string using convert, the sort order of the result is not the same as the sort order of the float.  e.g.  `3 < 20`, but `'20' < '3'`.

The routine `FloatToSortable` solves that problem. If you pass a bunch of floats through the routine, and sort on the results, you'll get the same order as if you sorted the floats. e.g. `FloatToSortable(3) < FloatToSortable(20)`.

And so in your code, where you write

```
CONVERT(varchar(2555), salary)
```

replace it with

```
dbo.FloatToSortable(salary).
```

You say that you can't add a function to your database.  That's unfortunate.  I've just used functions here to avoid repetition.  You can certainly use the same premise to create a single expression that will give the same result, although that expression will be much longer and harder to understand.

```
-- FloatToSortable takes a FLOAT parameter and returns a string
-- such that the sort order of FLOATs X and Y will match the
-- sort order of strings F(X) and F(Y).
--
-- The internal format of FLOAT is an 8-byte double-precision
-- float, starting with the SIGN where 0=positive and 1=negative,
-- followed by the EXPONENT and then the MANTISSA. 
-- If it weren't for the SIGN we could just sort by the binary
-- value.  Because of the sign we need to XOR the binary
-- before we can sort on it.  
--
-- If the parameter is positive, XOR with 8000000000000000
-- If the parameter is negative, XOR with FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
--
-- Then we convert each byte to a Sortable string. We could
-- use hexidecimal, but it's simpler just use letters A..O
--
-- This function is working with salaries, so we don't have
-- to worry about NANs and Infinities, but it should work
-- with all values.

-- NybbleToSortable
-- Given an integer in range 0..15 return a character
-- We just map the number to a letter, 0 -> 'A', 15 -> 'O'

create function NybbleToSortable ( @a tinyint )
returns varchar(16)
as
begin
  return char(@a + ascii('A'))
end

go

-- XorToSortable
-- Take the nth byte of @a, XOR it with the nth byte of @b,
-- and convert that byte to a Sortable string.

create function dbo.XorToSortable ( @a varbinary(8), 
                                    @b varbinary(8), 
                                    @n int )
returns varchar(16)
as
begin
  declare @aa tinyint, @bb tinyint, @x tinyint
  set @aa = cast ( substring ( @a, @n, 1 ) as tinyint )
  set @bb = cast ( substring ( @b, @n, 1 ) as tinyint )
  set @x = @aa ^ @bb
  return   dbo.NybbleToSortable ( @x / 16 ) 
         + dbo.NybbleToSortable ( @x % 16 )
end

go

create function dbo.FloatToSortable ( @x float )
returns varchar(16)
as
begin
  declare @m varbinary(8), @b varbinary(8)

  set @b = cast(@x as varbinary(8))

  if @x < 0 
    set @m = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
  else
    set @m = 0x8000000000000000

  return   dbo.XorToSortable ( @b, @m, 1 )
         + dbo.XorToSortable ( @b, @m, 2 )
         + dbo.XorToSortable ( @b, @m, 3 )
         + dbo.XorToSortable ( @b, @m, 4 )
         + dbo.XorToSortable ( @b, @m, 5 )
         + dbo.XorToSortable ( @b, @m, 6 )
         + dbo.XorToSortable ( @b, @m, 7 )
         + dbo.XorToSortable ( @b, @m, 8 ) 
end

go

-- Create some test data

create  table dbo.sal ( salary float, salbin as dbo.FloatToSortable(salary)) ;
go

declare @x float
set @x = pi()/9876543

while abs(@x) < 170
  begin
    insert into sal ( salary ) values ( @x )
    set @x=@x * -2.014159265
  end

select * from sal order by salbin

-- result is:
--  salary                 salbin
--  ---------------------- ----------------
--  -51.6508818660658      DPLGCMKPOHCLNIAP
--  -12.7318092715982      DPNGIJFAELIPCGOM
--  -3.1383581745746       DPPGOEKEHICIIKOI
--  -0.773597202236665     EABHDOLBBEIDLJLO
--  -0.190689716730473     EADHJHHKLHHKMEDG
--  -0.0470045237516562    EAFHOPAFOHHBPGCJ
--  -0.0115864939704268    EAHIEFFHBKJCNPMF
--  -0.00285604090440349   EAJIJKHCLHAGILBG
--  -0.000704006722693307  EALIOOFNBDCOOAMG
--  -0.000173535842863177  EANJEBBKHFNPDPAD
--  -4.27761380502506E-05  EAPJJCKPBGJEEFHA
--  -1.0544207791913E-05   EBBJODBPBNKKNIPE
--  -2.59912004745334E-06  EBDKDCGOKEJGGCDL
--  -6.4067639356036E-07   EBFKIAKBLGBGEJKE
--  3.180862629353E-07     LOJFFIKOCNMOIIKB
--  1.29042429395639E-06   LOLFKGFEIEBGJGMI
--  5.23504172442538E-06   LONFPFBFEPNNJAIF
--  2.12377138161667E-05   LOPGEEPEJEJMLAHP
--  8.61579547748313E-05   LPBGJFPGGEGGLLMK
--  0.000349528825712453   LPDGOIBOOABNBNJK
--  0.00141798166313501    LPFHDLHCDHKFMEBP
--  0.00575252124882327    LPHHIPPEKKCBMBFH
--  0.0233370441794017     LPJHOFKKIGCELCJB
--  0.094674597011311      LPLIDMJICJOMPBIA
--  0.384079459692908      LPNIJEMCADJMJBKO
--  1.55814797226306       LPPIOOCMJBHDCNED
--  6.32115319420792       MABJEINMGCAIIEAO
--  25.6438916046025       MADJKENGBEIHOPME
--  104.033102255957       MAFKACBOFIOMLAIO
```

Comment: Bonus: select dbo.floattosortable(-4.111252207503383E211) result is: BECALMINGDECIMAL.  What's can you spell?

Comment: @algorithmic, was this helpful?

Comment: is "FloatToSortable" a function available in standard SQL or did you create it? if you created it, show us the code.

Comment: I created it just for you.  All the code is there.  Maybe you need to scroll down?  Code. Full documentation.  Examples.  It's all there for you.

Comment: I cannot use functions created in the database. Secondly for broader purposes, you may need to explain why your solution works conceptually.